# Change alert button to open screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have an alert button which I would like to change, so instead of clicking a cell to go inside it I would like use the button.

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0:

    {
        NSLog(@"More button was pressed");
        UIAlertView *alertTest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"More more more" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertTest show];

        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        break;
    }
```

How can I integrate that with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BNRDetailViewController *detailViewController =
                              [[BNRDetailViewController alloc] init];

    // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                         animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you mean that you're trying to use the button on the alert view that appears, you'll need to add a non-cancel button and implement the UIAlertViewDelegate to deal with the alert view button being clicked. In the method that deals with the button click, you can initialize your BNRDetailViewController and push it. [alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548-CH3-SW1) is the UIAlertViewDelegate method you'll want to implement

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want the button that is revealed when the user swipes the tableview row to push the viewcontroller instead of displaying an alert view, this is what you want to do:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0:

    {
        BNRDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[BNRDetailViewController alloc] init];

        // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                     animated:YES];

        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to push the new controller with a click from the alert view, you'll have to add the UIAlertViewDelegate and a message for the other button on your alert view. Then call the clickedButtonAtIndex Method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{


if (buttonIndex == [alertView firstOtherButtonIndex] && [alertview.title isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController
                                     animated:YES];

  }
}
```